# Fstab: Mount a network share using host name (not IP address)

Tags: windows, samba, fstab, share

I have a CIFS share working correctly in `fstab` using

```
//192.168.x.x/directory/to/folder /media/my/directory cifs ...
```

However since our company network dynamically allocates ip addresses, is there a way to mount a CIFS folder using something like:

```
//mypc.servername.local/directory/to/folder /media/my/directory cifs ...
```

So that even if the computer's IP address gets changed, the Pi can still access the drive?

Comment: Simple answer: Yes.

Comment: @Huczu Excellent, can you send me a link or write something to elaborate how?

Comment: But you got it. Use hostname/servername instead of ip address, but network should be configured. More information at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/how-to-make-a-machine-accessible-from-the-lan-using-its-hostname

Comment: @Huczu Turns out the samba config file wasn't correct (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out our Windows server doesn't use wins, while the samba.conf file by default has wins enabled.

The settings we changed were as follows:

```
[global]
wins support = no
# wins server = w.x.y.z
dns proxy = yes
```

Then remounting using //mypc.servername.local/... in fstab worked correctly.

Comment: You probably need to ensure Avahi is installed for mDNS. The Windows DHCP or DNS server is probably set to "Register DHCP leases in DNS".

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to setup or reconfigure the existing DNS server on your company network. You need to instruct your company DHCP server to point to aforementioned DNS server.

A competent Windows admin will know how to do this easily with Windows Server.

Most cheap SOHO routers should have an easy way to to do this via web-interface too. Some even manage the "fake" .local TLD by default ! Sadly ISPs often hide router manuals or rebrand COTS routers in a confusing way. If you get stuck persitence in the search for manuals will be needed.

Alternatively , dnsmasq is both a DHCP and DNS server for Linux and makes this very easy. You can even run it on a Raspberry Pi !

http://www.andrewoberstar.com/blog/2012/12/30/raspberry-pi-as-server-dns-and-dhcp